# Obtain value from another column based on selected list value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Say I have two columns, the currency and the exchange rate and on another sheet in the same workbook, I'm referencing the currency as a drop down list.  I want to be able to pull the value of the exchange rate, which is in another column and plug that into a formula.

To add to that, the values, normalized at one currency, is then summed.

```
Currency    Exchange Rate to USD

USD                  1
EUR                  1.307
JOD                  3.59
KWD                  1.41
```

And the desired output:

```
     Expense      Currency    Value    Value(USD)(Invisible)
       X             USD       1000     1000
       Y             EUR       4321     5647.55
       Z             KWD       1000     3590


      Total                   10237.55  (always calculated in USD, the nominal currency)
```

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to do this using VLookup. Thanks in every case.

Comment: If you have found it out on your own -- don't hesitate to write answer on your own. That would be benefitial for the potential visitors of this website who might face the same problem and find your question via a search engine!

Answer (score 0):

For your hidden values in USD (column D) you could use the formula
`=C1*vlookup(B1,sheet1!$A$1:$B$4,2,false)` to multiply the value times the conversion rate on sheet 1 and drag it down column D on sheet 2